# How to disable password authentication for every users except several

Tags: openssh

I want to share my answer for question in title, which I can't find quickly.

There many topics how to disable password auth at all:

```
UsePam yes # it will not be used
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
kbdInteractiveAutentication no
```

but no topics how to enable for paticular user:

```
Match User myuser
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    KbdInteractiveAutentication yes
```

Also useful command to test sshd config is:

```
sshd -T -C user=myuser,host=127.1,addr=127.1
```

Please, note that "127.1" will not work on every system, so you may need paste 127.0.0.1 here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not about *password authentication* specifically, you could force usage of `pam_access.so` and have your `/etc/security/access.conf` look like so:

```
+ : myuser : <ip/net here or ALL>
- : ALL : ALL
```

Comment: It is anti-hacking security policy for my server.  Many attacks and scans use password auth method to check weak passwords. So when potential attacker will want to hack me, he goes away with nothing.

Comment: Then you might consider using `pam_access.so` globally as that would affect not only `SSH`'s password authentication but also every other service configured to use PAM.

Comment: Allmost all other services are behind pf(4)